# Simple way to share maps on a network drive?

Tags: network, maps

I am not an expert in web GIS and I would like to share some maps I created with non GIS aware colleagues from other offices. I have looked at various options but I can't find one that suits my needs.

The problem I have is that I do not have access to a server and therefore I cannot use web map services and the only way I have to share my maps is by using a shared network drive. Deploying the maps on a cloud service like ArcGis Online is not possible either as it is sensitive data.

I was thinking of deploying my data on the shared drive and than ask my colleagues to use ArcGis Explorer to access the maps. I think this solution might work but I would like to avoid the need of installing the software as I don not want to give them too much control on the data.

All I want for them is to be able to double click on a file that will display a map where they can see where things are and possibly include some chart and tabular information, possibly using a web browser.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

---

I tried qgis2leaf, it works but is quite basic. Do anyone have other suggestions?

Comment: Would generating tiles and then using some javascript (e.g. openlayers) in a browser be simple enough?

Comment: That would probably be the preferred option but I don't have experience of javascript and currently I have very little time to learn.

Answer (score 3):

If you can install Qgis in you computer, with the leaflet plugin you only need to do just load your layers into the software and export them with the leaflet plugin.
Here is a useful tutorial: http://www.qgistutorials.com/de/docs/leaflet_maps_with_qgis2leaf.html

It will work on local file system (bear in mind, this will generate a static map, if you update your source data you need to export them again)

Comment: Thanks Tamas, very interesting solution, I will give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much data you need to display creating a [Geo PDF](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00sm00000007000000) export in Arc may be suitable:

> PDF files exported from ArcGIS can include feature attributes from the
>   feature's attribute table using functionality built in to Adobe
>   Acrobat and Adobe Reader. This option can be enabled by choosing the
>   Export PDF Layers and Feature Attributes option from the Advanced tab
>   of the Export Map dialog box:

1. Set your map/layout/graphs/symbology...etc up in ArcMap
2. File menu>Export and select General tab PDF > Advanced tab > Export PDF Layers and Feature Attributes
3. Place PDF on network drive and provide insctructions on how to click and access data attributes

If the pdf needs refreshed daily you could use a little of arcpy and Windows task scheduler to update the pdf every night.

Comment: Thanks, I have already created something like that but it really doesn't work as the area covered by the shapefiles is huge and I would like to give the user the ability to zoom to a particular location and retrieve information from the shapefile's attribute table.